# Pending request in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I noticed that when I was "away from keyboard" over 5-10min and I make a call to backend (`GET, POST or something`) the first call is directly the request in question and the browser not send before the `OPTIONS` request so the call remains pending and if I make a second call works fine, because send first the `OPTIONS` (the browser understands that it doesn't send `OPTIONS` call before) and after successfull response start the `GET`...

I think the browser cache the `"Authorization of request"` and that's is why the first call after some minutes goes in pending: browser doesn't send OPTIONS call before...

I use Chrome and I never tested with Firefox or something else...

It's a big problem because if a user is `afk` for some reason, he need to press button twice for what he need to do.

Anyone know fix/trick to avoid this? I'm working on angularjs applications, and the http request are made with `$http`.